# Make variables show a column with awk

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, awk

I have this variable:

```bash
collumn=2
```

I want to make it change with the 2rd column of the line that starts with `john` from a file, with awk.

For example, in this file `sample.txt`:

```
bill|copper|real|bruce
john|gold|fake|jhin
johny|silver|geniue|madrit
```

This doesn't work:

```bash
collumn=2
awk -F '|' /^jonh/ -v collumn="$2" sample.txt
echo "$collumn"
```

I want it to print `gold`.

Basically I want to change the value of a variable with awk.

Comment: i think its better.. i wasnt enough focused. i want to change the value of a variable with awk

Comment: damn i didnt see that too

Comment: well collumn=2 doesnt mean anything really im just making a program and the user will give how the line starts and the column, so the program will put the string in that location to the variable.. i want collumn to change value and take the value of the string in the 2nd collumn (2nd as an example) and starts only with john (john as an example) im not that good with my english :P     
 
in your file the command yould be like awk -F '|' /^ij/ -v collumn="$2" sample.txt if i echo collumn it wil print me kl in my file i think it will do the awk for johny too and i ll lose the value that i want

Comment: i made it 2 so it would be simpler

Comment: thanks :D sorry for the trouble im still new and its a bit hard for me

Answer (score 3):

You are using two languages: Bash and AWK.

[Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) ([which is](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638918/why-is-bash-the-default-shell-in-most-os) your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)) and [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) are both [programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language), and they both allow you to store data in [variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)). ***But [variables in your shell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters) and [variables in AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variables) are completely separate.*** Furthermore, variables in AWK no longer exist after your AWK script finishes. That is, once your `awk` command is done running, your AWK variables are gone.

You can pass text of the form `var=val` as a [command-line argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments) to the `awk` command. This assigns a variable *in AWK*. It does not affect shell variables in any way. When you use the `-v` option (e.g., `-v var=val`), that tells the `awk` command to assign the variable before it runs your AWK script, but it is still an AWK variable, not a shell variable.

Your goal is to assign text from a specific column of a matched line to a *shell variable*. You can do that. **But first, let's solve a simpler problem.** This command finds rows that start with `john` and *displays* the contents of the second column of each such row. If you have just one row that starts that way, it displays one item. If you have no such rows, it displays nothing, and if you have multiple rows that start with `john`, then it will display multiple items on separate lines:

```bash
awk -F '|' '/^john/ { print $2 }' sample.txt
```

The AWK script in that command is `/^john/ {print $2}`. I have enclosed it in [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) (`'` `'`) so that it is treated as a single string, and not [modified by the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions), before being passed to the `awk` command. Otherwise the shell would interpret the AWK script as five [separate words and operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation) for the shell itself (*not* AWK), which would lead to it taking just `/^john/` as the AWK script. Everything after it would be treated as filenames to pass to `awk`, which would not work. The shell [would also](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) expand [`$2`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters), and would perform [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and [filename expansion (globbing)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) on the result (though enclosing `$2` in [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) as in your question would prevent splitting and globbing). You don't want any of those things to happen. In general, it is a good idea to enclose your AWK scripts in single quotes so they are passed faithfully to the `awk` command.

With the `sample.txt`  file shown in your question, that command produces this output:

```
gold
silver
```

It prints text from two matching lines, rather than just one. Since you want just `gold`, you probably don't really want to match all lines that *start* with `john`. Instead, you probably want to match only lines where the entry in the first column *is `john` exactly*. (One of the benefits of solving a simpler version of a problem first is that it can help you to refine your knowledge of precisely what problem you want to solve.) You can select only lines whose first column entry is *exactly* `john` like this:

```bash
awk -F '|' '$1 == "john" { print $2 }' sample.txt
```

That displays:

```
gold
```

**Now let's solve the full problem.** Assigning to shell variables is not something that you can do in an AWK script. Not only is this not part of the AWK language, but the `awk` command [would have to be implemented as a part of your shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) in order for it to be possible. This doesn't mean you can't do what you want to do--you absolutely can. It just means that, instead of attempting to write AWK code to assign to a shell variable, you must use the shell itself to do it.

You have an `awk` command that displays the value you want assigned to a variable. So you can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) in the shell to help you perform the assignment. This command assigns it to a shell variable called `entry` (but you can use whatever name you like instead of `entry`, such as `column`):

```bash
entry="$(awk -F '|' '$1 == "john" { print $2 }' sample.txt)"
```

That works because the shell [replaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323162/how-do-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-variable) `$(` `)` and everything inside it with the *output* produced by running the command inside it. That's [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution). Note that, when you assign a shell variable like this, you must *not* have any spaces around the `=` sign.

(By the way, you may notice that the text `john` is colorized above as though it were not effectively quoted. That is actually a bug in the software that provides syntax highlighting on this website, which happens because it does not fully parse the contents of the outer `"` `"`, so it does not know that the inner `"` `"` is inside `$(` `)`. This is not a problem when you actually run the command, however.)

You can verify that `gold` was assigned to the `entry` shell variable by running:

```bash
echo "$entry"
```

That will display:

```
gold
```

For more information on variables in the AWK language, see this section [6.1.3 Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variables) in [Gawk: Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/), which is the official documentation for GNU awk (`gawk`). Although it documents GNU awk, it explains what is specific to GNU awk and what can also be used in other implementations of the AWK language. The `awk` command in your Ubuntu system be either [`mawk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/mawk.1.html) or [`gawk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gawk.1.html), depending on what software you have installed and how you have configured it. One way to see which is to run `awk -W version`.